# How to write data that has been read and parsed into another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a python script that reads a file like this:

```
test.com|test,login|login,news|new,ranking|ranking,festival|festival,talent|talent,login|login,dashboard|dashboard/dashboard
test2.com|test2,net|c6,login|login
etest.com|efile
test3.com|folde,shop|lab_shop,2013|2013,crm|crm
test4.net
test5.net|dashboard
```

In the first line:

`'test.com'` is domain name

`'test'` after pip is project folder

`'login ,news , ... '` is subdomain

I want to read the domain name and the sub-domain and then create a file like this:

```
test.com

login.test.com

news.test.com
```

I've written this script:

```py
with open('domains') as fp:
  for line in list(fp):
    line1 = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")[0]
    line1 = line1.split('|')[0]
    print(line1)
fp.close()

result:
test.com
test2.com
etest.com
test3.com
test4.net
test5.net
```

This shows the domain name.
But how do I write the sub_domain?

Comment: Where `|` is the delimiter, are you saying, field 0 is the domain, and field 2 is the subdomains (separated by `,`), the rest should be disregarded?  Each line in your input has completely different fields so this needs clarifying.

Comment: Yes, I have defined domains to be separated from the subdomain by commas and folders to be separated by pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that below code been useful :

```
with open('domains') as fp:
  for line in list(fp):
    line1 = line.rstrip("\n").split("|")
    baseDomain = line1[0]
    print(baseDomain)
    for lbl in line1:
      domain = lbl.split(',')
      try:
        print(domain[1]+'.'+baseDomain)
      except IndexError:
        folderName = domain[0]
fp.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, How can I save the folder name after creating that file?

Comment: Instead of used print command, must be use write commands that you want to create the file.If not enough my explanation, please give me some more information about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it (note you don't need to call `fp.close`, `with` already takes care of that):

```
with open('domains') as fp:
  for line in fp.read().splitlines():
    parts = line.split('|')
    domain = parts[0]
    subdomains = [subdomain.split(',')[0] for subdomain in parts[1:]]
    urls = ['.'.join([subdomain, domain]) for subdomain in subdomains]
    [print(url) for url in urls]
```

Output:

```
login.test.com
new.test.com
ranking.test.com
festival.test.com
talent.test.com
login.test.com
dashboard/dashboard.test.com
test2.test2.com
c6.test2.com
login.test2.com
efile.etest.com
folde.test3.com
lab_shop.test3.com
2013.test3.com
crm.test3.com
dashboard.test5.net
```

Comment: No need to call `fp.close()` if you use the `with` context manager. Also, you could replace `for line in list(fp)` with `for line in fp.read().splitlines()` so you don't have to split on \n afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, but The lines were duplicated when I tested the original file, My original file is like this:‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍ 
 
 ```nano.com|nano,leader|nano,news|nano,ranking|ranking,festival|festival_beta,edu|edu cog.com|cog,net|c6,login|login nanoin.com|nanoin,textile|nanoin,water|nanoin,nanocoat|nanoin```     Output has been repeated     ‍‍‍‍‍```nano.nano.com
nano.nano.com
nano.nano.com
ranking.nano.com
festival_beta.nano.com
edu.nano.com
cog.cog.com
c6.cog.com
login.cog.com
nanoin.nanoin.com
nanoin.nanoin.com
nanoin.nanoin.com
nanoin.nanoin.com```

Comment: Of course you get duplicates, this file structure is different from what you posted in your question. However, you can easly fix it by changing `subdomain.split(',')[0]` to `subdomain.split(',')[1]`.